# Can a conventional QFT explanation of the "antitritium deficit" be offered such that it jibes with the Standard Model and QFT principles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, antimatter

*the "antitritium deficit" used in the question refers to the attached image/data from Brookhaven National Laboratory STAR facility analyzed circa 2011, the parent article abstract is here:
[link to abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0108)
i have attempted to contact the author about this question but the email posted is currently invalid, in 10 years since publication - no conventional explanation has been offered, apparently. Since many stackexchange members are fluent in QFT, i feel comfortable asking this question here
[image: plot from article cited]

Comment: Good question. It isn't obvious why so much more tritium than antitritium is observed and the paper does not comment on this.

Comment: i feel SO stymied that the author is unavailable, i did a follow-up search on arXiv to get a more recent email for the author but alas - not successful ~ an old friend had an expression "well, it's a Mystery!" i personally Love these intriguing Q's in science But we'll *never* know unless follow-up research is performed...

Comment: The linked paper is primarily about detecting anti-helium. Does this effect persist in literature directly about anti-tritium? Since this asymmetry appears in a side channel of a "can we detect this" measurement, and doesn't seem to be commented on in the paper, I wouldn't let myself get too attached to it.

Comment: Referenced in more recent [review](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physrep.2018.07.002). People like "excitement", even if noisy.